# R: Using map() and plot() with the same projection

Tags: r, coordinate-system

I am trying to plot a shapefile (SpatialPolygonDataFrame in R) of 180 census tracts on top of an outline of the US using `map()`. The .prj file for the census tracts lists the projection as follows:

```
 PROJCS["USA_Contiguous_Albers_Equal_Area_Conic",GEOGCS["GCS_North_American_1983", 
 DATUM["D_North_American_1983", 
 SPHEROID["GRS_1980",6378137.0,298.257222101]],
 PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0], 
 UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]], 
 PROJECTION["Albers"], 
 PARAMETER["False_Easting",0.0], 
 PARAMETER["False_Northing",0.0], 
 PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",-96.0],
 PARAMETER["Standard_Parallel_1",29.5], 
 PARAMETER["Standard_Parallel_2",45.5],
 PARAMETER["Latitude_Of_Origin",37.5],
 UNIT["Meter",1.0]]
```

And when I call `proj4string()` on the tracts, I get the projection in this format.

`"+proj=aea +lat_1=29.5 +lat_2=45.5 +lat_0=37.5 +lon_0=-96 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=NAD83 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0"`

I tried setting the projection within `map()` to match this .prj file, but when I go to plot my census tracts on top, they don't show up anywhere.

```
 map("usa", project="albers", par=c(29.5,45.5))
 plot(tracts, add=TRUE)
```

I feel I'm misunderstanding either how to add the projection properly, or how to over-plot polygons on top of `map()`.

Comment: For map, is there a way to set the central meridian too? Or do you have rotate the data to "0"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your best bet is to get the US outline from another source. I don't think the `map` function really handles projections quite the same way as the `sp` functions.

For example, your USA map with `albers` above - look at `par()$usr` or show the coordinates with `axis(1);axis(2)` - those are small numbers around 0 to plus or minus 1. Your projection string for your data has units of `m` - metres. `maps` has not scaled the USA to metres.

I suggest you get the `raster` package and use `getData` to get the USA outline from the GADM database. Instructions are there. Then you can project it to your data coordinates using `spTransform` from the `rgdal` and `sp` packages.